# Java: How to cast a class to a subclass?

Tags: java, class, casting

I have a abstract class called `GameObjectsCls` and a subclass called `AllTilesCls`...

```
public abstract class AllTilesCls extends GameObjectsCls
```

...But for some reason I can't cast a reference of super-class to a sub-class to get a `public Boolean` field value from that subclass?

```
if((AllTilesCls)(handler.getObjectPlacement().getSelectedObject()).built){
    ...
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `if(((AllTilesCls)(handler.getObjectPlacement().getSelectedObject())).built())`

Comment: According to [this operator precedence table](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html), the dot for member selection has higher precedence that the type cast. So you were trying to cast the result of the `built()` method, not the object you wanted to call it on. The added parentheses in @DavidPérezCabrera’s comment make up for that. Next time please quote the error message you get, and it will be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(((AllTilesCls)(handler.getObjectPlacement().getSelectedOb‌​ject())).built())
```

– David Pérez Cabrera 5 mins ago

This worked.